# Search textfile after specific search term and change the result in the output

Tags: c#, parsing, text

I have a text file in the format

> Name Harry.Potter
>
> Number 123.123234
>
> Name Lisa.Simpson
>
> Number +44.123234

If the line *starts* with the word `Name`, I want the dot (`'.'`) to be exchanged to a blankspace (`' '`).

How can I change only the dots in the lines starting with `Name` and **not** `Number`?

I use `System.IO.File.WriteAllLines` and `System.IO.File.ReadAllLines` in other parts of the code so it would be nice from my part if this function could be done in the *similar way*.

Comment: `if (line.StartsWith("Name")) line = line.Replace('.', ' ');`

Comment: Did you try anything at all? It sounds like you did so share your code and explain what's not working specifically. It's also disappointing to see high rep users grabbing for low hanging fruit.

Comment: Please don't add texts like "Solved" to the title. Instead, mark the most helpful answer as accepted by clicking the checkmark below the downvote button.

Answer (score 2):

Quite direct: if line `StartsWith` `"Name"`...

```
var data = File
  .ReadLines(@"c:\MyFile.txt")
  .Select(line => line.StartsWith("Name")
     ? line.Replace('.', ' ') // change '.' to space if starts with Name
     : line)                  // otherwise, leave intact
  .ToArray(); // Materialization if you want to write back to the same file

File.WriteAllLines(@"c:\MyFile.txt", data);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Dmitry. Worked perfectly. 
I didnt know about "startswith" 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
//read all lines
var lines = File.ReadAllLines(@"c:\temp\test.txt");
//iterate through all lines
for (int i=0; i<lines.Length; i++)
{
    //check if line starts with name, and if it does, replace dot with space
    if (lines[i].StartsWith("Name"))
        lines[i] = lines[i].Replace(".", " ");
}
//write lines bact to file
File.WriteAllLines(@"c:\temp\test.txt", lines);
```

Comment: Thanks Nino. Didnt know about the StartsWith.